# Make a SQL Server plugin using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, plugins

Is it possible to do a plugin for SQL server in C#?

I want to do a string matching algorithm on items that are in the database, without loading the objects into my c# application. Does anyone know if this can be done in c# (maybe a plugin for SQL or something like this).

I think that it is something like Map Reduce in MongoDB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [SQL Server's CLR Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131089(SQL.100).aspx). It lets you run .NET code directly inside the SQL Server process, to do anything from adding types and functions to modifying tables and rows. For instance, you could write a custom [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) to do calculations very similar to a "reduce", all inside MSSQL.